# Hide user id in rails (devise gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the project that I am undertaking is required to have a `user` so each user has own tasks but the problem is the current login `user_id` is appearing on URL. Is there any way I can hide the `user_id` on URL all the time. I am using the `devise gem`.

*Routes.rb*

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'accounts' 

   resources :users do
      resources :tasks, only: [:index, :create, :edit]do
         collection do
            get :board
         end
      end
   end
```

*Routes:*

```
              homes_index GET    /homes/index(.:format)                                                                   homes#index
         new_user_session GET    /accounts/sign_in(.:format)                                                              devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /accounts/sign_in(.:format)                                                              devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /accounts/sign_out(.:format)                                                             devise/sessions#destroy
        new_user_password GET    /accounts/password/new(.:format)                                                         devise/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /accounts/password/edit(.:format)                                                        devise/passwords#edit
            user_password PATCH  /accounts/password(.:format)                                                             devise/passwords#update
                          PUT    /accounts/password(.:format)                                                             devise/passwords#update
                          POST   /accounts/password(.:format)                                                             devise/passwords#create
 cancel_user_registration GET    /accounts/cancel(.:format)                                                               devise/registrations#cancel
    new_user_registration GET    /accounts/sign_up(.:format)                                                              devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /accounts/edit(.:format)                                                                 devise/registrations#edit
        user_registration PATCH  /accounts(.:format)                                                                      devise/registrations#update
                          PUT    /accounts(.:format)                                                                      devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /accounts(.:format)                                                                      devise/registrations#destroy
                          POST   /accounts(.:format)                                                                      devise/registrations#create
                     root GET    /                                                                                        homes#index
    message_message_clear GET    /messages/:message_id/message/clear(.:format)                                            message#clear
                 messages POST   /messages(.:format)                                                                      messages#create
              new_message GET    /messages/new(.:format)                                                                  messages#new
               user_tasks GET    /users/:user_id/tasks(.:format)                                                          tasks#index
                          POST   /users/:user_id/tasks(.:format)                                                          tasks#create
           edit_user_task GET    /users/:user_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format)                                                 tasks#edit
                    users GET    /users(.:format)                                                                         users#index
                          POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         users#create
                 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                                                     users#new
                edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                users#edit
                     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                                                     users#show
                          PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                                                     users#update
                          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                                                     users#update
                          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                                                     users#destroy
```

If there is any additional information required, please let me know.

Comment: Check out [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem

Comment: Can users access only their own tasks or can they access other users' tasks as well?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky that's an insane gem. I will check more

Comment: You can customize devise routes without using another gem, in rails you can [Overriding Named Route Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters) and devise too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

```
rails g migration add_nickname_to_users nickname:string
rake db:migrate
#restart server
```

**User Model**:

```
#user.rb - file
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :nickname, use: [:slugged, :history, :finders]

# on changing a nickname will be changed "slug" also.
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    nickname_changed?
end
```

**Controller:**

```
# one of these definitely will work.
@user = User.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `resources :users do` to `resource :users do`

OR

```
resources :users

namespace :users do
  resources :tasks, only: [:index, :create, :edit] do
    collection do
      get :board
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want user A to see user B's tasks at all, then don't nest the tasks controller under the users controller. Instead you can have a "top-level" tasks controller that scopes itself to the current user. So every logged in user will go to `/tasks` and they'll see their own tasks list.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :tasks


# app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @tasks = current_user.tasks
  end

  def show
    @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
  end

  ... etc ...

end
```

As long as you make sure that you scope all queries to the `Task` object to `current_user.tasks`, Devise will ensure that not only will your users not be able to find out each other's user ID, but they also can't buck the system and load random task IDs that they shouldn't have access to.